# Proof that light has a width

Tags: waves, visible-light, friction

Now this is my suggestion so please guide me. Take a plane mirror. We know that light reflects from it. This is a case of regular reflection meaning the surface is smooth. But we experience friction on a plane mirror. This means there are asperities on the plane mirror. This means that light reflects on a surface with some irregularities. This can only happen if light has greater width than the microscopic grooves on the mirror. Hence my conclusion that light has a width. Please guide me and tell me if I am wrong

Comment: https://www.eckop.com/resources/scatterometer-resources/optical-scattering-versus-surface-roughness/

Comment: and in a lot more detail - https://opg.optica.org/directpdfaccess/e4a2de34-aa4a-4c45-af086eaaf25ff82b_213652/oe-19-10-9820.pdf?da=1&id=213652&seq=0&mobile=no

Comment: any wave is characterized by three quantities: (1) temporal extent - frequency, (2) spatial extent - wavelength, (3) intensity extent - amplitude.

Comment: You don't even need to consider reflection. Any beam of light spreads due to diffraction. The narrower the beam, the wider the spread. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction

Answer (score 2):

Light does indeed have a characteristic length scale, and specular reflection is indeed related to that length scale. But that length scale is called “wavelength” rather than “width”.

In particular, the amplitude of a light wave does not provide a length scale. The amplitude is a measure of the strength of the electromagnetic field, so it would be closer to a force scale.

The length scale is the wavelength, which determines the scale at which a surface must be smooth for specular reflection.

Comment: That's not the phenomena that you need to explain this no? Unless I misunderstand, he means that we can see the light reflecting on some surface (imagine just a normal, white wall and a laser pointer) despite the fact that we are not in its theoretical reflected direction. So he concludes the light cone must have a width. This width is "independent" of the light wavelength. It's just how the light is produced. By e.g. just a cover with a certain diameter hole.

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 I think you are misunderstanding the question. The OP can clarify if needed

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 I mean to say that light reflects after hitting a plane mirror. But since the mirror has microscopic grooves in it, the light ray is obviously bigger than those irregularities.  So in conclusion light has a width.

Comment: @MathsGuy I have added some material to the answer

Comment: You should explain then @Dale in what sense light does not see the rough surface of the mirror. I.e. something about resolution given by the wavelength, because anything smaller than that will see the light as a plane wave and the light does not resolve this texture. (Or if you have a better intuitive picture without going into actual scattering, by all means.) Clearly, OP has a misconception about amplitude, wavelengths and also most importantly the extend of a wave package. This is the "widths" I would assign to light: Full width half maximum

Comment: *For light that is of gaussian form. But this measure of widths has "nothing" to do with the resolution, except that it scatters "off less (i.e. rate of scattering is smaller)" if there's less amplitude that interacts with another particle, here the mirror.

Comment: @Dale  My question is how can a wavelength be the width? Shouldn't amplitude be the width?

Comment: @MathsGuy As I explained in the answer the amplitude is not a length scale. The amplitude is closer to a force scale than a length scale. The amplitude cannot be a width or anything else related to distance. It doesn't even have the right units

Comment: @Dale You did misunderstand the question. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which picture you prefer, but I'll just walk you through the picture of a wave.

You probably have in mind the picture of light being a oscillating wave of electric field and perpendicular to it a magnetic field. Now this picture is actually "wrong" (in the sense that it is misleading).

1. The Amplitude is depicted as an arrow. However, this arrow is not actually there in real life. Its length simply should tell you about the amplitudes "size" (i.e. the strength of the fields) NOT its spatial extend.
2. Light(-cone) does have spatial extend. Clearly, a flashlight shines brighter (ideally only if) you look directly into it, rather than if you look at some other spot. This **is** the size you are referring to. This translates to the following: $A(x)$ be the Amplitude of your light cone, $x$ the space coordinate. Then $A(x)$ will vanish if you go away from the flashlight source. We can assign a size to this, by e.g. saying the size is when $A(x)$ drops below a certain value. We can think of each ray of light going along, say, the x-direction as fixing coordinates $y$ and $z$ and then we can think of this ray as a infinitesimal wide line. Then we can look at the rough surface, and this ray of light will reflect "irregularly" (i.e. not in the direction one would naively expect the whole light cone to reflect to on a perfect surface.) Repeat this for all $x$ and you'll see how the whole light cone reflects.
3. The other one, is as previously mentioned, the wavelength of light, i.e.the distance between buldges. This length scale plays a role when discussing what "resolution light has". This is a problem of scattering on structured particles and whether or not one can see this structure, but it also has implication for macroscopic things like Diffraction.